# Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to automatically register request handling classes with reflection.

This is an example of manually adding a handler for execution of a certain request.

```cs
// generic manual method of registration
server.RegisterHandler<GetData>(base.ExecuteMessage);
```

Here is the attempt to register with reflection. The invoke method will not accept the 'ExecuteMessage' method getting the error "Error CS0428  Cannot convert method group 'ExecuteMessage' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?".

```cs
// registration with reflection
foreach (var type in serviceTypes)
{
    // registerHandlerMethod definition:    RegisterHandler<T>(Func<IMessage<T>, object> processMessageFn)
    // ExecuteMessage definition:           object ExecuteMessage(IMessage message)

    registerHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(server, new object[] { base.ExecuteMessage });
}
```

Is it possible to cast the ExecuteMessage method in any way to get this to work?

Edit: Added example with problem below

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new Server();

        // generic manual method of registration
        server.RegisterHandler<GetData>(ExecuteMessage);

        // registration with reflection
        var serviceTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(GetData) };
        var registerHandlerMethod = typeof(Server).GetMethod(nameof(Server.RegisterHandler));

        foreach (var type in serviceTypes)
        {
            registerHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(server, new object[] { ExecuteMessage });
        }
    }

    static object ExecuteMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        return null;
    }

    internal class GetData
    {

    }

    internal interface IMessage<T> : IMessage
    {

    }

    internal interface IMessage
    {

    }

    internal class Server
    {

        internal void RegisterHandler<T>(Func<IMessage<T>, object> processMessageFn)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please post a [mcve] which we can run ourselves.

Comment: How is `RegisterHandler` declared?

Comment: " Cannot convert method group" because it doesn't know the type of the delegate to convert it to.You need to call the `Func` constructor with reflection somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reason for "Cannot convert method group..." is because the compiler doesn't know the type of the delegate to convert it to.**

You need to call the Func constructor with reflection as well. This is complicated by the fact that `IMessage` is generic also.

You also need to redefine `ExecuteMessage` as generic to match the delegate type:

```cs
static object ExecuteMessage<T>(IMessage<T> message)
{
    return null;
}
```

I think the code you need is as follows:

```cs
var executeMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(ExecuteMessage), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var type in serviceTypes)
{
    var messageType = typeof(IMessage<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(messageType, typeof(object));
    var func = executeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).CreateDelegate(funcType, this);  // don't pass this for static methods
    registerHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(server, new object[] { func });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will do the trick! Will check first thing in the morning :)

Comment: It seems im running into an exception with this, ArgumentException. Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type. This is occuring on the line with createdelegate call. Seems like the typing is correct to me...

Comment: However I tried simply without the typing on the IMessage and passed this 'registerHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(genericArg).Invoke(server, new object[] { new Func<IMessage, object>(ExecuteMessage) });' which seems to be working. I was expecting this to actually throw the argument exception..

Comment: That would depend whether you modified `ExecuteMessage` as I said

Comment: Ah right, my bad. Unfortunately the method is from an api which I cannot modify. Thanks for the help